# VBA Excel Worksheet Change Autofit Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code in a standard module, which works fine:

```
Public Sub AutofitRows()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Then I have this code in the Data worksheet module, which doesn't autofit all the rows for some reason:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then

Call AutofitRows

End If

End Sub
```

Can somebody please explain how to correct this?

Thanks.

Comment: what error message are you getting? If it's a question of excel Autofit behavior rather than an error, show us an example of the data rows where AUtofit doesn't appear to be applied properly

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

There is no error message - it just doesn't autofit any of the rows

Comment: ok, please show us wome data so we can try it

Comment: It looks like you've done the right things, except that it's better to use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange` to change just the rows that have been used. It is the row height that you're trying to autofit and not the column width ?

Comment: @grahamj42 Thanks, amended. And it's the row height that I want to autofit.

Comment: @Philip What's the best way to post the data? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
Public Sub AutofitRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Rows("3:3")
    rng.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Assuming your below code resides on Worksheets("Data").Also the procedure will be called when value in cell B3 will change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
        Call AutofitRows
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd like the column width to remain the same and the row height to change.

Comment: This may be of relevance: the other cells (on other rows) I'd like to autofit are lookups to another sheet.

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("anotherSheet").Range("3:3").EntireRow.AutoFit

Comment: Are you sure that event 'change' fires?

Comment: @KazJaw How do I check that? Thanks

Comment: It stops at the autofit line of the sub procedure. The "Data" sheet that requires the autofitting contains lots of tables, if that has any bearing?

Comment: @user1423997 What error are u getting? Is there any merged cells in row 3?